# How to securely access media content from an app folder to another?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, image, express

(First, sorry for my English. It's not my first language)
I have the following folder structure for my two Node.js + TypeScript apps. The second one also uses React on the frontend:

```
firstApp/
   dist/
   media/

secondApp/
   client/
     dist/
   server/
     dist/
```

As you can see, my first app has a media folder (you can consider it's only images) where it stores some private media content it receives. I want to access these files from my secondApp and display them to users. After my user is logged in and access an specific page, it retrieves some info from the Database and maps it. One of this info is the name of the file I want to access. So, how can I securely ensure only my secondApp has access to that media content and can display it to users?

I thought about using something like `express.static` to serve that, but I don't know it's secure or the best option. I've also searched a lot, but I can't find something to clarify it for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.